# Connect privatenet with ethereum wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I created a private net within a folder in Documents. It works fine. I tried connecting ethereum wallet with private net...But ethereum wallet created another node in **.ethereum** folder and shows corresponding node.

When I moved private net folder to **.ethereum** ...wallet was connected and was able to see accounts in it.

Does ethereum wallet connects only to the geth in **.ethereum** folder?
Is there any way by which wallet will connect to the geth in any folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum-Wallet checks for `geth.ipc` file in **.ethereum** folder. If it finds one, it connects with that else it creates one and starts a new geth instance.

So if you have your private net setup -n different folder, Try adding `--ipcpcath "path_of_you_.ethereum_folder"` flag to geth instance you are runnnig.

By default when you start private net, it creates the geth.ipc file in same folder, but by using --ipcpath flag you can tell geth where to create ipc file. Since ethereum-wallet makes IPC connection to you node, it must know the path of you **geth.ipc** file.

Comment: So anyhow geth.ipc file should be in .ethereum folder ?

Comment: Yes, because ethereum-mallet reads only the geth.ipc in .ethereum